# How can I make an iron ingot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've tried making an iron pickaxe but to do that I need three iron ingots.

How can I obtain an iron ingot?

Comment: [Just smelt the iron ore](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Iron_Ingot), you can find information like this on their [wiki page](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_Wiki)

Comment: Have you tried searching google for this yourself? The first link will take you to the [wiki page](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Iron_Ingot) which answers your question.

Comment: Come one now! Read my answer or ardaozkals!

Answer (score 4):

As spencer stated, you need to [smelt the iron ore](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Ingot).

To smelt it, you need a furnace and something to fuel it. You can see the fuels [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Smelting#Fuel_efficiency) (in case of removal, the fuel you should go for is probably Coal).

Answer (score 2):

You need to mine a block called [Iron Ore](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Ore) which can be found underground at any layer. You need to stone pickaxe or higher to mine iron ore. You can find other ores such as [Coal Ore](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Coal_Ore) and there are other ores which are rare and they are at the bottom of the world. Now, you have to smelt the iron ore using the furnace with any fuels. Wait, then go back to the furnace and you get iron ingots. When you take it, you earn XP.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to obtain an iron ingot, these are the ways:

- Mine an iron ore with stone pickaxe. With your furnace, use fuel to obtain the iron ingot (such as coal, planks, wood)
- Can be found on some structures, such as a village with a blacksmith, a dungeon with a chest contained with iron ingot.
- There is a chance that a zombie would drop iron ingot when killed.
- Iron golems drop iron ingots when killed. Iron golems are located in some villages.

The most common way to obtain iron ingots is to smelt iron ores.

[image]